# STM() Error in Matrix::Matrix(x) : invalid 'data'

Tags: r, lda

I am attempting to run a structural topic model using [stm()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stm/stm.pdf) in R.

when I input the following code:

```
stm.out <- stm(dtm2,K=0,prevalence=covs2,verbose=F,data = brady_sub2)
```

Following error pops up:

> Error in Matrix::Matrix(x) : invalid 'data'

The class of brady_sub2 is:

```
class(brady_sub2)
```

> [1] "data.frame"

and dtm2 is:

```
class(dtm2)
```

> [1] "dgCMatrix"
> attr(,"package")
> [1] "Matrix"

When I attempted to convert brady_sub2 into matrix:

```
stm.out <- stm(dtm2,K=0,prevalence=covs2,verbose=F,data = as.matrix(brady_sub2))
```

same error pops out:

> Error in Matrix::Matrix(x) : invalid 'data'

so when I attempted converting dtm2 into matrix:

```
    stm.out <- stm(as.matrix(dtm2),K=0,prevalence=covs2,verbose=F)
```

> Error in UseMethod("asSTMCorpus") : no applicable method for 'asSTMCorpus' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"

So when I attempted to use asSTMCorpus:

```
    stm.out <- stm(asSTMCorpus(dtm2,vocab = Terms(as.DocumentTermMatrix(dtm2)),K=0,prevalence=covs2,verbose=F))
```

> Error in .TermDocumentMatrix(t(x), weighting) : argument "weighting" is missing, with no default

Do you guys have some idea in what is going on? what should I try next?